# Java output of a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

New to recursion. The output of this code is `79`, How is this answer reached? When written down I find the base case never being reached. `(-3+4) + (2 * -3) = -5 => (-5+4) + (2 * -5) = -11...` Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of recursion or basic algebra?

```
int result = negative(-3);

public int negative(int num)
{
    if(num >= 20)
    {
        return -5;
    }
    else
    {
        return negative(num + 4) + 2 * num;
    }
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.println("The final answer is " +result);
}
```

Comment: It's `negative(num + 4) + (2 * num)` not `negative((num + 4) + (2 * num))`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first case isn't `(-3+4)` it's `negative(-3+4)` which is `negative(1)` + (2 * -3). If you change the first line of `negative` to

```
System.out.println(num);
```

You can see how the numbers recursively reach the output you've already given.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this out yourself:

If the function is sent a number greater than, or equal to 20, it returns -5

Otherwise, it returns 2*num + (itself again with num+4)

We get:

(2*-3) + (2*1) + (2*5) + (2*9) + (2*13) + (2*17) + (-5)

Doing the above, you get 74